# Cannot Assign a Null Value to a Nullable Int32? via Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Cannot assign a null value via a TextBox Binding to Int32?.
If the TextBox is empty then Int32Null Set is not called.
A red border is around the TexBox indicating a validation exception.

This just does not make sense as Int32? is nullable.  If the user removes the integer value from the TextBox I want the Set called so the property is assigned to null.

When it starts int32Null = null and the TextBox is not red.

I tried implementing Validation and set validation = true if the TextBox is empty.  But Set is  still not called and TextBox is red indicating a validation error.

It seems like I should be able to assign a null value to a nullable via binding.

```
    <Window x:Class="AssignNull.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Int32Null, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=StringNull, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Int32? int32Null = null;
        private string stringNull = "stringNull";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Int32? Int32Null
        {
            get { return int32Null; }
            set { int32Null = value; }
        }
        public string StringNull
        {
            get { return stringNull; }
            set { stringNull = value; }
        }
    }
```

Set StringNull does get called and value passed is not null but rather string.empty.

Since Set is not called on Int32Null I don't know what is getting passed.

It was also passing a string.empty to Int32?.   Had to convert an empty string to null.

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Int32?), typeof(String))]
    public class Int32nullConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Int32? int32null = (Int32?)value;
            return int32null.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string strValue = value as string;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue.Trim())) return null;
            Int32 int32;
            if (Int32.TryParse(strValue, out int32))
            {
                return int32;
            }
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a false assumption on how the [type converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126043.aspx) ought to handle this. So if they do not do what you want, namely turn an empty string into `null` you'll either have to write your own or use a [`Binding.Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) that does the conversion for you.

Comment: If the target type is Int32? what would be your assumption about what an empty string should be converted to given you assert my assumption is false?

Comment: @BalamBalam: You just made another assumption, namely that an assumption *should* be made. I try to not make assuptions as they lead to errors, if there's a possibility to look the behaviour up in the documentation that is what i would do.

Comment: @BalamBalam: An empty string is not null (both are valid values for a `string`, which is the type of the property that you're binding to), and is not convertible to an empty `Nullable<int>` by using built-in type converters.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Actually there is a [`NullableConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.nullableconverter.aspx) which does return null if the input string `IsNullOrEmpty` but does not appear to be used.

Comment: @H.B.: By built-in converter, I was referring to the default converter that would be used to convert between `int` and `string`. Using a custom converter (such as `NullableConverter`) is the way to go.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: `NullableConverter` is not any more "custom" than the `Int32Converter` which is the default type converter for ints though.

Comment: @H.B.: I think we're arguing about something we agree on. I only mean that `NullableConverter` is "custom" in the sense that you must explicitly specify it as the converter for your binding.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: If you know of a way to do that please let us know, because that is not trivial, after all it is a type converter and not a value converter.

Comment: @H.B. Congrats; you win the hair-splitting contest. If you manage to turn that skill into something helpful (or even useful), please let us know, because that is also non-trivial.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: I think you missed the point here, i was not being sarcastic nor did i mean to offend you. This is not hair splitting at all, type converters are vastly different as they are usually applied statically to types and properties via attributes, i for one cannot get it use the `NullableConverter`, so i am dead serious, if you know, tell us.

Comment: @H.B.: I don't wish to prolong this digression. I said that achieving the behavior that the OP required would require a custom converter, which it does. Perhaps my error was in saying "type converter" (note that I did not say `TypeConverter`, but was using the term more to refer to its application rather than its inheritance hierarchy).

Comment: @AdamRobinson: This was a misunderstanding then; since this question is on this topic and because i mentioned both type and value converters in my answer i made this distinction here.