# Autogenerate columns null values

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to save null values to a decimal column(allows nulls on db) on a wpf datagrid (with autogenerate columns).

It doesn't allow me to save nulls and shows red error box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code in AutogeneratingColumn event:

> if (e.Column.ToString() ==
>   "System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn")
>               {
>                   (((System.Windows.Controls.DataGridBoundColumn)(e.Column)).Binding).TargetNullValue
>   = string.Empty;
>               }

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are running into a problem that I had but it was a simple text box (not a datagrid).  You think you are passing a null but you are really passing string.empty which is neither null nor a decimal.  I fixed it with a converter to convert string.empty to null.  H.B. (the same H.B.) that edited your question answered mine.

[Cannot Assign a Null Value to a Nullable Int32? via Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050054/cannot-assign-a-null-value-to-a-nullable-int32-via-binding)

Answer (score 0):

to which kind of database are you binding your datagrid to ? for instance if you bind it to a datatable with ado.net, the datatable is not aware of the underlying sql schema unless you update it yourself. --> see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310128
with linq2sql it should work fine without this update, with others like MySql i don't know.