# TextBox with CurrencyFormat and PropertyChanged trigger doesn't accept text right

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, currency, string-formatting

I have a `TextBox` in a WPF window bound to a dependency property of the window of type `double` (see below).  Whenever the user types in the `TextBox` when

1. The `TextBox` is empty, or
2. All of the text is selected,

the typed text is accepted incorrectly.  For example:  If I type a '5' in either of these scenarios, the resulting text is "$5.00", but the caret is located before the '5', after the '$'.  If I try to type "52.1", I get "$2.15.00".

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="154" Width="240" Name="ThisWindow"
        Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.AppWorkspaceBrushKey}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow,
                                Path=Amount,
                                StringFormat={}{0:c},
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 MinWidth="100" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If I remove the UpdateSourceTrigger attribute, it types correctly, but doesn't maintain the currency format.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a converter.   TextBox actually only deals with text and when you bind to something other than text it has to make some assumptions (guesses).   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050054/cannot-assign-a-null-value-to-a-nullable-int32-via-binding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by it trying to apply the formatting after every character press.

As an alternative, I usually just style the `TextBox` so it only applies formatting when it's not being edited

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=C}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: That's what I meant at the end of my question when I said that removing the update trigger doesn't maintain the format.  I'm building an accounting app, and I'd like to keep the formatting if I can.

Comment: @gregsdennis This style will maintain the currency format, but only when the user doesn't have focus on the `TextBox`. Once the user clicks on the `TextBox`, it will get rid of the formatting and just show the number. Typing in the `TextBox` will still fire a `PropertyChanged` event on every key stroke, however it won't attempt to format the number while you type.

Comment: I get that.  I would like to maintain the format while the user types in the box.

Comment: Then try a converter.  @Rachel +1 I think not formatting while they type is a nice option.

Comment: is there any clever way to do this in a more reusable way so I don't need to apply this to every distinct textbox

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9129164/302677) a while back. There are some ways listed there, but nothing as quick and easy as a style.