# Workaround for caret textbox with binding an property changed XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a lot of textboxes binded in twoway mode ot a different properties with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and I have one annoying problem: when I enter or delete a value - caret moves to the begin of the string.
I found a solution here:
[TextBox with CurrencyFormat and PropertyChanged trigger doesn't accept text right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910681/textbox-with-currencyformat-and-propertychanged-trigger-doesnt-accept-text-righ)

but I cannot implement it correctly. I probably miss something.

Here is my XAMLbinding for one of textboxes:

```
enter code here <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFirstPersonCameraMinPosY" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Normal"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=CameraLimitationParameters.FirstPersonCameraPosition.MinValue.Y, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True, Delay=0, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ToStringConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
                                         MaxLength="40" Margin="10,0,0,0" MinWidth="150" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MaxWidth="150"></TextBox>
```

and here is my style:

```
enter code here<Page.Resources >
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CameraMode"
        MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="settingsManager:CameraBehavior"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <settingsManager:ToStringConverter x:Key="ToStringConverter"></settingsManager:ToStringConverter>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

What did I miss an how to apply this style for all textboxes independently of binding property without duplicating code? 
And will this workaround work for my case? Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was because I set IsAsync=True in TextBox. In this case Async need to be set to false.