# TextBox for Time

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application I have a `TextBox` where the user can input a time-value in the format `HH:mm:ss`.

The xaml of the `TextBox` looks like:

```
<TextBox xMinWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="FileTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" StringFormat="T" ConverterCulture="de-DE" />         
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

The property `FileTime` in the ViewModel is of type `DateTime`.

If I try to type in the value 13:15:45 the `TextBox` shows me 13:15:04 at the moment I type the 4. If I type the last 5 the result in the `TextBox` is 13:15:045 which is not a valid time.

How can I make my `TextBox` to accept a single number as second and doesn't append a leading zero?

Comment: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TimePicker&referringTitle=Documentation ?

Comment: Why don't you try changing the StringFormat?

Comment: I've already tried to change the StringFormat to HH:mm:ss -> There I have the same situation. If I change it to HH:mm:s than if the user types in 13:14:5 and leaves the input-field the seconds stay at 5. In this case I expect the second to become 05

Comment: @Tomtom why would you expect that? `HH:mm:s` means: Give me 2 digits for hour, if hour is < 10 prefix it with a 0 `:` Give me 2 digits for minute, if minute < 10 prefix it with a 0 `:` Give me 1 digit for seconds, if seconds > 10 give me 2 digits.

Comment: Why don't you updating model on lost focus `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`? Is it highly required to update it in `PropertyChanged` ?

Comment: What about leaving the text unformatted if the user is entering data, and only formatting it after the TextBox looses focus? This is a common solution for numeric formats as well, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9911143/302677)

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish what you ask, but it's not clear _which_ of those varied ways would be appropriate, as your question is vague on the details of what the expected behavior is. If you want to accommodate partial input that invalid, why use `PropertyChanged` as the trigger? Conversely, if you want to use `PropertyChanged` as the trigger, doesn't that imply that you want to always interpret whatever the user typed as a valid `DateTime` if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which is working perfect for me and is easily reuseable for each `TextBox`.

I've written an `AttachedProperty` which looks like:

```
public class TextBoxExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditStringFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "EditStringFormat", typeof (string), typeof (TextBoxExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnEditStringFormatChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalBindingExpressionProperty = DependencyProperty
        .RegisterAttached(
            "OriginalBindingExpression", typeof (BindingExpression), typeof (TextBoxExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(BindingExpression)));

    private static void OnEditStringFormatChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = d as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue != null && e.OldValue == null)
        {
            textBox.IsKeyboardFocusedChanged += TextBoxOnIsKeyboardFocusedChanged;
        }
        else if (e.OldValue != null && e.NewValue == null)
        {
            textBox.IsKeyboardFocusedChanged -= TextBoxOnIsKeyboardFocusedChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void TextBoxOnIsKeyboardFocusedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        if (GetOriginalBindingExpression(textBox) == null)
        {
            SetOriginalBindingExpression(textBox, textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty));
        }

        BindingExpression bindingExpression = GetOriginalBindingExpression(textBox);

        if (textBox.IsKeyboardFocused)
        {
            Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
            Binding newBinding = new Binding(parentBinding.Path.Path)
            {
                ElementName = parentBinding.ElementName,
                Path = parentBinding.Path,
                Mode = parentBinding.Mode,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = parentBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger,
                StringFormat = "H:m:s"
            };
            foreach (ValidationRule validationRule in parentBinding.ValidationRules)
            {
                newBinding.ValidationRules.Add(validationRule);
            }
            textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindingExpression.ParentBinding);
        }
    }

    public static void SetEditStringFormat(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(EditStringFormatProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetEditStringFormat(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(EditStringFormatProperty);
    }

    private static void SetOriginalBindingExpression(DependencyObject element, BindingExpression value)
    {
        element.SetValue(OriginalBindingExpressionProperty, value);
    }

    private static BindingExpression GetOriginalBindingExpression(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (BindingExpression) element.GetValue(OriginalBindingExpressionProperty);
    }
}
```

And the usage is just:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtHour" MinWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxLength="8" Background="Transparent"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"
         attachedProperties:TextBoxExtensions.EditStringFormat="H:m:s">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="FileTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" StringFormat="HH:mm:ss">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validationRules:StringIsTimeValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```